# fabric.api.run converts stderr to stdout for SSH

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I run compilation on serve using fabric, server is Linux and client is Windows, channel is SSH.

1. On server 'scons' prints compilation errors to stderr. It is okay.
2. But fabric.api.run('scons') executed from client prints compilation errors to STDOUT. It is not good and because of this my IDE fails to detect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `fabric.api.run` combines stdout and stderr to the same stream. As @miku said, in fabric 1.0 you can disable this behavior setting `combine_stderr=False`. Alternatively, just redirect stderr to /dev/null

```
run('scons 2>/dev/null')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `combine_stderr=False` (at least in 1.0).

See also:

- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run
- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/usage/interactivity.html#combining-stdout-and-stderr

Comment: After fix [52b41ff01ca352a9d63b76946d1f20a61cc3ecae](https://github.com/vvavrychuk/fabric/commit/52b41ff01ca352a9d63b76946d1f20a61cc3ecae) this parameter become effective.


But still I've debugged until fabric/paramiko until I saw that there is not MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA message from server which supposed to carry stderr. There is only MSG_CHANNEL_DATA with both stdout, stderr.

I suspect it is OpenSSH server issue. Could you help on this?